# OnClick in react portal works only after second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

Here is my code:

```
const portal: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
portal.style.cssText += 'position:relative;z-index:10000';
document.body.appendChild(portal);

const DocumentUploadItem = ({ condition }) => {
  const child = (
    <div onClick={() => console.log('click')}>
      Test
    </div>
  )

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(child, portal);
}
```

When I'm using this DocumentUploadItem, and click on it, in the first time nothing happens, after second click it prints 'test' and works correctly further. I tried to set the event handler on the document to test if it bubbles up, but nothing happened again. How can I fix it?

Comment: I also have this problem. If your find a solution, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem, looks fine to me.

Here's what I tried:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const portal = document.createElement("div");
portal.style.cssText += "position:relative;z-index:10000";
document.body.appendChild(portal);

const DocumentUploadItem = ({ condition }) => {
  const child = <div onClick={() => console.log("click")}>Test</div>;

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(child, portal);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <DocumentUploadItem />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Correct me if I made a mistake.
If possible, provide a link to a sandbox where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was instead of assigning jsx to variable, to assign a component, like this:

```
const child = () => <div></div>
```